# Why I can't connect to my chatHub of signalR when I visit my website through nginx reverse proxy in docker?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, signalr, nginx-reverse-proxy

I build a signalR chatHub asp.net core web application, and I can visit it normally without nginx,I can connect to the chatHub and send message, but after I use the nginx reverse proxy ,I can open the website but can't connect to my chatHub ,I don't konw why? Is there any more settings needed?
Thanks for help.

Both the nginx and asp.net core webapplication are in docker.

Comment: Maybe this article can help: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: Thanks a lot, It really solved my problem.

Comment: I'd like to，But I can't find the upvote icon around your comment, there just a flag.Is it can only be upvoted of the answer rather than a comment ?